# Ordnance survey missing counties from boundary line shapefile?

Tags: united-kingdom

I would like to make a shapefile of Great Britain's counties.

I have downloaded the [boundary-line data](https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey/Boundary-Line-stylesheets/archive/master.zip) from ordnance survey.

When I pull Data/GB/county_region.shp into [mapsahper](http://www.mapshaper.org/) I get this map:

[image]

What happened to all the other counties? Scotland, Wales etc. Has anyone else tried using this ordnance survey map, and knows if you can get all the counties for Great Britain?

Comment: EU NUTS is another source

Comment: Gdam is another source. Get it from diva gis.

Comment: not all of the UK is within a county, especially in the devolved regions - you may be missing unitary authorities in England too.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_counties_of_the_United_Kingdom for more details

Comment: Mrs Thatcher moved me from a historic county to a metropolitan borough. Whatever that is...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland does not have Administrative 'Counties' as a ubiquitous level 2 administrative unit. Some places are Unitary Authorities (54 regions), others are Metropolitan Boroughs within Metropolitan Counties (36), so just traditional counties will have numerous gaps. What you need is Administrative level 2 boundaries and not counties. Admin Level 0 is the entire UK in one geography, Level 1 are the countries of Scotland (Alba), Wales (Cymru), England, & Northern Ireland (Ulster) in four geographies, and Admin Level 2 are the counties and the other geographies I list above with complete UK coverage in a consistent manner and detailed outlines.

1)  This is what you get from [GADM](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata) and I think it is just what you want. Level 2. Just go to the link and select the UK and select admins.

[image]

2)  Download piecemeal from OS.

3)  Obtain from EU NUTS.

Essentially, if you take number 1 then all the work is done for you and I suspect all 3 sources have the same data originator.

Comment: I'm just curious. Was the level of detail the same as the OS boundaries you obtained? Just from a visual instruction inspection is fine.